# What triggers a full garbage collection in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, performance

I'm wondering what are the exact situations that trigger Full Garbage Collection in Java.

The obvious ones are:

- Running out of old gen
- Running out of perm gen
- Calling System.gc()

What about other cases that cause full gc? Particularly:

- Not having enough free space in Survivor Space to copy objects from Eden.
- Minor collections not being able to cope with allocation rate of new objects (don't know how though).

I'm running Sun Java 1.6 and using Concurrent Mark-Sweep and ParNew for new gen.

Comment: As Chin Boon suggests, none of those "obvious" ones will necessarily lead to a full GC, it depends entirely on how the active garbage collector algorithm works.  In particular, it's my understanding that a lot of garbage collectors more or less ignore `System.gc()`.  (And don't forget that it's even possible for a GC algorithm to not even have a concept of a "full collection" - this might sound far-fetched but I've not seen the [G1 collector](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/g1-intro-jsp-135488.html) do so on our apps.)

Comment: What do you think JVM with G1 does when it runs out of heap space? Keep on allocating? It has to stop everything until it can free memory. There is a switch that explicitly turns off System.gc() hint, but I haven't seen CMS or G1 ignoring it by default.

Comment: I guess it depends how you define "full collection" - I don't believe it's a first-class term within the context of the JLS or VM spec.  The meaning will vary depending on the particular GC algorithm you're running, and might not even make sense for a given GC impl.  What I was trying to point out is that the only possible general answer is "it depends", with all other specifics deferred to the internals of the particular garbage collector.

Comment: I think there is a common denominator to full collection. Full collection is defined as a collection during the whole duration of which the threads are stopped. Even though CMS has a short pause, the whole JVM is suspended for the whole duration of the collection when a full collection happens. Full collection with CMS is actually two CMS runs - one for old gen and one for perm gen. I imagine it's exactly the same with G1.

Comment: This article gives an example of Full collection in G1 (when incremental collection fails): http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html. If Hotspot GC logs recognize the term Full GC, I think it's quite official.

Comment: Yes, good point, G1 has a stop-the-world collection.  This isn't a *necessity* of GC though, for example a collector could divide the heap into two and collect a full one in the background while using the other, without stopping the world.  For example the [Zing JVM's GC](http://www.azulsystems.com/technology/garbage-collection-tuning) doesn't do any full collections by your definition.  My point is that there are very few things that you can assume about GC - other than that the collector will recover a weakly reachable object *eventually* (pre-OOME), it can more or less do what it wants

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've observed one more situation that triggers a full GC in Java Hotspot VM 1.6 64bit on Ubuntu, using Concurrent Mark-Sweep:

If -XX:PermSize value does not equal to -XX:MaxPermSize (e.g. is smaller), an occasional Full GC happens when java needs to expand the PermGen (even though it does not need to allocate more memory than MaxPermSize). 
So setting -XX:PermSize and -XX:MaxPermSize to be the same seems like a good idea.

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? PermGenSpace does not have any impact on full gc. DO you mean xmx and xms params?

Comment: @Amareswar Oracle says: "The permanent generation is included in a full garbage collection"

Answer (score 2):

This greatly depends on your jvm options and the jvm that you at using.

For this reason, I recommend that you look at the book "Java Performance" bý John and Hunt.

Comment: There have to be some general rules though at least per JVM implementation and garbage collector.