# Java Garbage Collection - Occurrence of one FULL GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am getting only one FULL GC in the beginning. Anyone knows why this FULL GC is happening. verbose GC logs are pasted below.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_79-b15), built on Apr 10 2015 11:34:48 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
Memory: 4k page, physical 12028696k(8289940k free), swap 0k(0k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+AlwaysCompileLoopMethods -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:-CMSPrecleaningEnabled -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:InitialHeapSize=2621440000 -XX:MaxHeapSize=2621440000 -XX:MaxNewSize=1572864000 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:NewSize=1572864000 -XX:OldPLABSize=16 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseParNewGC 
2015-08-19T16:13:33.068+0100: 101.480: [GC2015-08-19T16:13:33.068+0100: 101.480: [ParNew: 1228800K->153600K(1382400K), 0.2028820 secs] 1228800K->183823K(2406400K), 0.2029750 secs] [Times: user=0.86 sys=0.01, real=0.20 secs] 
2015-08-19T16:24:52.983+0100: 781.395: [GC2015-08-19T16:24:52.983+0100: 781.395: [ParNew: 1382400K->117199K(1382400K), 0.1762650 secs] 1412623K->292710K(2406400K), 0.1763560 secs] [Times: user=0.88 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs]
```

.........................

```
2015-08-19T16:34:49.144+0100: 1377.556: [GC2015-08-19T16:34:49.144+0100: 1377.556: [ParNew: 1234692K->7088K(1382400K), 0.0146160 secs] 1520104K->293793K(2406400K), 0.0147080 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2015-08-19T16:34:52.364+0100: 1380.776: [GC2015-08-19T16:34:52.364+0100: 1380.776: [ParNew: 1235888K->5535K(1382400K), 0.0112050 secs] 1522593K->293080K(2406400K), 0.0113010 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2015-08-19T16:34:55.607+0100: 1384.018: [GC2015-08-19T16:34:55.607+0100: 1384.018: [ParNew: 1234335K->6833K(1382400K), 0.0117390 secs] 1521880K->295111K(2406400K), 0.0118300 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2015-08-19T16:34:58.699+0100: 1387.110: ****[Full GC2015-08-19T16:34:58.699+0100: 1387.110: [CMS: 288277K->201657K(1024000K), 0.8300700 secs] 1485407K->201657K(2406400K), [CMS Perm : 33686K->33656K(33920K)], 0.8387470 secs] [Times: user=1.10 sys=0.03, real=0.83 secs]**** 
2015-08-19T16:35:01.927+0100: 1390.338: [GC2015-08-19T16:35:01.927+0100: 1390.338: [ParNew: 1228800K->27726K(1382400K), 0.0202150 secs] 1430457K->229384K(2406400K), 0.0203230 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
```

---

```
2015-08-19T16:42:07.420+0100: 1815.832: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 514340K(1024000K)] 522144K(2406400K), 0.0052180 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2015-08-19T16:42:07.426+0100: 1815.837: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2015-08-19T16:42:07.749+0100: 1816.161: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.324/0.324 secs] [Times: user=1.16 sys=0.14, real=0.32 secs] 
2015-08-19T16:42:07.750+0100: 1816.161: [GC[YG occupancy: 255614 K (1382400 K)]2015-08-19T16:42:07.750+0100: 1816.161: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.1178140 secs]2015-08-19T16:42:07.868+0100: 1816.279: [weak refs processing, 0.0001000 secs]2015-08-19T16:42:07.868+0100: 1816.279: [scrub string table, 0.0010920 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 514340K(1024000K)] 769955K(2406400K), 0.1190980 secs] [Times: user=0.74 sys=0.01, real=0.12 secs] 
2015-08-19T16:42:07.869+0100: 1816.281: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2015-08-19T16:42:08.560+0100: 1816.971: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.690/0.691 secs] [Times: user=2.18 sys=0.35, real=0.69 secs] 
2015-08-19T16:42:08.560+0100: 1816.972: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2015-08-19T16:42:08.563+0100: 1816.975: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.003/0.003 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2015-08-19T16:42:09.191+0100: 1817.602: [GC2015-08-19T16:42:09.191+0100: 1817.602: [ParNew: 1235443K->7655K(1382400K), 0.0144670
```

I would like to know,

1) Does the FULL GC shown above stop the work because looks like it doesn't GC the young generation? Is the assumption correct that this FULL GC is only for Tenure and permanent generation.

2) FULL GC shows CMS. Is this the same Concurrent Mark Sweep algorithm which does concurrent Garbage collection? If yes, why it doesn't show all the steps in the FULL GC as it is shown when a Concurrent Mark Sweep algorithm run ( pasted above)

3) Is the permanent CMS GC is normal here? Why FULL GC triggered here only one in the beginning

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "in the beginning". The Full GC happens 21 minutes after start.

Comment: You might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546392/what-triggers-a-full-garbage-collection-in-java

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is there an actual problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was - there was one FULL GC was taking more time ~800 msecc and after that no full GC seen.

I got the reason for that. By making –XX:PermSize  equal to –XX:MaxPermSize, eliminates this FULL GC.