# Why CMS GC is getting triggered if Tenured memroy not used more than 70%

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

In my application i have specified the below jvm arguments which means that CMS GC will initiate only when my tenured memory used more than 70%. My application is not using more than 50% tenured memory still the CMS is getting triggered.

```
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70

-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

My question is that why CMS is getting triggered while we are mentioning JVM when to triggered CMS(when tenured memory usage >70%) ?

Comment: There are many conditions which can trigger full gc. This has been answered here i believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546392/what-triggers-a-full-garbage-collection-in-java

Comment: Is there any JVM argument where we can control full GC?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to look at the different issues that could be triggering it. For example, increasing NewSize to avoid allocation failures there or increasing PermGen. You really need to look at the gc log and see what is triggering the event, it should tell you.